# Issues With Netlify Lambda Function Response.. Keep Getting Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, aws-lambda, netlify

I'm trying to setup a lambda function to authenticate, validate, and handle sending of a contact form..

I'm new to lambda functions so my code may be flawed, but no matter what I do I can't seem to modify the response that is sent back to my vue.js app.

I keep getting "response undefined" ...

Can some explain what I'm doing wrong, and maybe a better way to change the data returned based on what's going on in my function?

```
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');

const AUTH_API_ENDPOINT = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/'
const FORM_API_ENDPOINT = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1217/feedback'
const captchaThreshhold = 0.5

exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
    const eventBody = JSON.parse(event.body)
    const captchaSecret = process.env.CAPTCHA_SECRET
    const captchaToken = eventBody.token
    const stringFormData = eventBody.formData
    let parsedFormData = JSON.parse(stringFormData)
    let formData = new FormData()
    var response;

    //build a new FormData object
    for ( var key in parsedFormData ) {
        formData.append(key, parsedFormData[key])
    }

    // first step is to validate the captcha..
    //let response_captcha
    try {
        response = await axios.post(`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${captchaSecret}&response=${captchaToken}`,{})
    } catch(err) {
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                status: 'error',
                message: 'Opps! The server tried to run an AI algorithm to determine if you are a spam robot, but the server did not respond properly so we are unable to continue contact form security verification... Please try again later or contact via phone instead. We appologize for the inconvenience.',
                error: err.message
            })
        }
    }
    
    // if we're over the threshold we continue and get a fresh JWT
    if (response.data.score >= captchaThreshhold) {
        // let response_jwt
        try {
            response = await axios.post(AUTH_API_ENDPOINT,{
            username: process.env.AUTH_USERNAME,    
            password: process.env.AUTH_PASSWORD,
            }).then(res => {
                // JWT token returned something.. lets try to submit our form data with authentication code..
                axios.post(FORM_API_ENDPOINT, formData, {
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${res.data.token}`,
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; charset="utf-8"',
                        ...formData.getHeaders()
                    }
                })
                .then( res => {
                    console.log('>> response came back from the Form endpoint : ',res.data.status, res.data.message)
                    return {
                        statusCode: 200,
                        body: {
                            status: res.data.status,
                            message: res.data.message
                        }
                        
                    }
                })
                .catch( err => {
                    console.log('>> something went wrong while trying to submit formData to form endpoint ',err.response.data);
                    return {
                        statusCode: 200,
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            status: 'error',
                            error: err.message,
                            message: 'Yikes! The form data was processed and sent to our email server but there was no response back. Our developer will look into this shortly. In the meantime, please try again later or contact via phone. We appologize for the inconvenience.'

                        })
                    }
                })
            }).catch( err => {
                    console.log('>> something went wrong while trying to fetch JWT from endpoint ',err.response.data);
                    return {
                        statusCode: 200,
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            status: 'error',
                            error: err.message,
                            message: 'Yikes! The form data was processed and sent to our email server for authentication but got no response back.. This is a server issue so our developer will look into this shortly. In the meantime, please try again later or contact via phone. We appologize for the inconvenience.'

                        })
                    }
                })
        } catch(err) {
            return {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    status: 'error',
                    error: err.message,
                    message: 'Yikes! The form data was processed and sent to our email server but the server was unable to authenticate the request. This is a server issue so our developer will look into this shortly. In the meantime, please try again later or contact via phone. We appologize for the inconvenience.'

                })
            }
        }
    } else {
        // user failed the captcha test.. is probably a robot..
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                status: 'error',
                message: "Error! Captcha Failed: our AI algorithms tried to determine if you are a robot or a human, it seems they couldn't decide, therefor for security reasons your form submission was blocked. Perhaps try again later, or contact via phone. We appologize for any inconvenience. :("
            })
        }
    }

    //send back the response..
    return response

}
```

Comment: firstly, mixing `async`/`await` with `.then` - you can do that, but the code is more complex than it needs to be ... the issue may be `}).then(res => {
                // JWT token returned something.. lets try to submit our form data with authentication code..
                axios.post` - needs to `return axios.post` there

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something more like:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.post(...args).then(response => {
      if(bool){
        axios.post(...moreArgs).then(response => {
          resolve('ok!')
        }).catch(reject)
      } else {
        reject('not bool!')
      }
    }).catch(reject)
  })
}
```

I feel like async / await makes this more complicated than without it.